# Как создать связанные записи разного типа

Tags: wordpress

Как сделать такую штуку:

Находимся мы на страничке поста. Пусть это будет к примеру сайт с фильмами. 
Под описанием есть графа "Актеры" и в строчку (как на скриншоте) выводятся актеры данного фильма. 
При клике на определенного актера нас перекинет на его страничку, где будет его биография.

Я знаю как делать таксономии, но это не похоже на таксономию.

Пример на скриншоте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По описанию похоже на обычные теги. Или есть какое-то отличие?

Comment: Переведи на понятный: "софты которые принадлежат single post" А также всё, что ты подразумеваешь под "single post", "single soft" и тп. Исправь вопрос

Comment: Это типа как таксономия (категория например) 
Только по клику на ее, человек попадает не на страницу archive,  а попадает на single page

Comment: Похожие/связанные записи?

Comment: @SeVlad, я испроавил описание на пример. 
Так будет легче понять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для записи типа `movie` добавляете custom field `actors`, куда загоняете ссылки на записи типа `actor`, например, с помощью [плагина Custom Field Suite](http://customfieldsuite.com/).

Comment: тогда получиться что у меня в поле будет ссылка, а не имя автора?

Comment: Автора или актера? Плагин позволяет привязывать связи с другими постами, а что именно уже выводить на странице - названия, ссылки или тубнэйлы - это уже ваше дело.

Answer (score 1):

> Под описанием есть графа "Актеры". и в строчку (как на скриншоте)
>   выводятся актеры данного фильма. При клике на определенного актера нас
>   перекинет на его страничку, где будет его биография.

Актёры - [отдельный типа поста](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_post_types#Custom_Post_Types), в котором посты - биография актёра.
Связи "фильм-актёры" через [произвольные поля](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F).

Comment: Так и сделал. 
Но как их связать?

Comment: В произвольные поля вставляешь IDшники. Но есть и готовые плагины для этого